# Create a nested hash to organize objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Payment` model which belongs to `Currency` and `PaymentMode`. `Currency` and `PaymentMode` have many `Payments`.

On the index page of my payments, I have a list of every payments, and I would like to be able to sort them by currency and by payment mode.

Let's say for example that I have three currencies (CHF, Dollars, Euros) and two payments mode (Cash and BlueCard).

What I want to obtain is something like this :

```
{
  CHF => {
           Cash => [array of corresponding payments], 
           BlueCard => [...]}, 
  Dollars => {
               Cash => [...], 
               BlueCard => [...]}, 
  Euros => {
             Cash => [...], 
             BlueCard => [...]}
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? For me, the best way would surely be to use objects. It's not Perl ;)

Comment: In fact, I don't think you realy need that hash. Could you please explain, how are you going to use it?

Comment: @roman.brodetski I need this hash to calculate the total price for each nested hash, for example cash payments in CHF and to generate a PDF with Prawn.

Comment: @iain I just mean a proper way to do it

Comment: @siekfried you mention there are models - do you have these already as   model objects from an ORM (probably Active Record) and then change them into hashes and arrays or something like that?

Comment: @iain yes I already have these as model objects from Active Record and I would like for example a class method in the `Payment` model to get my Payments organized.

Comment: @siekfried ok, then my advice is to stay away from hashes as the model classes already have everything you need. When asking a question about something you don't know, define what you want, not how you want it done, especially if you don't know the best way to get it done! :) Your question will skew the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
def get_hash_from_payments(payments)
  result_hash = {}
  payments.each do |payment|
    result_hash[payment.currency.symbol] ||= {}
    result_hash[payment.currency.symbol][payment.payment_mode.name] ||= []
    result_hash[payment.currency.symbol][payment.payment_mode.name] << payment #Or whatever info you need from payment.
  end
  result_hash
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, that's exactly what I was lokking for ;)